# Intercepting Bus messages in gstreamer plugin

Tags: plugins, error-handling, gstreamer

I'm writing a gstreamer plugin that uses a `uridecodebin`. I'd like to be able to intercept the error that occurs when the `uridecodebin` is unable to open a file (either because of a malformed URI, an unknown file format, or a non-existent file) before it's reported to the application using the pipeline. When I try to add a watch to the `uridecodebin`'s bus myself, it fails (`gst_bus_create_watch: assertion bus->priv->poll != NULL`) and I get a segfault.

How can I intercept the error before it's reported to the application so that I can gracefully fail internally? It isn't a critical error for the plugin as a whole if the file isn't loaded, and I'd like to be able to do some cleanup work when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read this page:
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-bus.html

Using wxpython, I do the following:

```
        # Create the bus to listen for messages
        bus = Gplayer.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
        bus.connect('message', self.OnBusMessage)


#   Listen for gstreamer bus messages
    def OnBusMessage(self, bus, message):
        t = message.type
        if t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
            Gplayer.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            self.OnStop(None)
            wx.MessageBox('Gstreamer Error - Unsupported file type, Corrupt file,\
             Unable to access or Invalid Output Device', 'Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
```

Or in your case, don't report anything.

EDIT:
You can parse the message to see part 1 which will be the error and part 2 which will be a more verbose explanation.

```
#   Listen for gstreamer bus messages
    def OnBusMessage(self, bus, message):
        t = message.type
        if t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
            print "Part 1",Gst.Message.parse_error (message)[0]
            print "part 2",Gst.Message.parse_error (message)[1]
```

This is what I get from the above for a missing file:
Part 1 Not Found
part 2 gstsouphttpsrc.c(1192): gst_soup_http_src_parse_status (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:source:
Not Found (404), URL: http://localhost/vvvv.mp3

Note: This assumes that you will add code to the existing watch

Edit 2:
With regard to your second comment, have you investigated gst_bus_new().
It appears at first glance, that it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have read this page, but when I add a watch it fails an assertion (`bus->priv->poll != NULL`) and the program crashes. I'm assuming this might be because there's already a watch on the bus (perhaps belonging to a parent element) and you can't set more than one watch. Do you know a way that would allow me to catch the specific error without replacing the existing watch altogether?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add code to the existing watch - I'm working inside a gstreamer plugin, I'm not writing a gstreamer application (which has the actual watch code inside of it).

Comment: @Aaron I'm facing the same issue here, did you find a solution for it, I have tried something like this but it seems not working: bus = gst_bus_new();
    gst_element_set_bus(element, bus );

    bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(bus , busCall, element);

Comment: A new bus needs to be created and attached to pipelines generated by a `GstRTSPMedia` object when creating an RTSP server.